# git commit - setting timestamps into the future

Tags: git

I need to make some commits using Git but I would like the timestamp in git-log to be in the future.

How can I do a commit in git that causes a future timestamp to register in the git-log?

Comment: Did you try changing your clock? =) I'd think that should work locally, but not sure what'd happen when others go to merge.

Comment: Timestamps aren't relevant to merges.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You should wait a bit.

Or you can do this:

```
/tmp/x 604% env GIT_AUTHOR_DATE='Wed Dec 19 15:14:05 2029 -0800' git commit -m 'future!'
[master]: created 6348548: "Future!"
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)

/tmp/x 605% git log 

Author: Dustin Sallings <dustin@spy.net>
Date:   Wed Dec 19 15:14:05 2029 -0800

    Future!
```

**Note** that there's both an author date and a committer date, so be sure to set the right one (or both).

Comment: It also works with ISO 8601 date format: "2029-12-19 15:14:05 -0800". I like that.

Comment: What is the difference between GIT_AUTHOR_DATE and GIT_COMMITTER_DATE?

Comment: @Blago: In git, the author (person who wrote the change) and committer (person who put the change in the repository) are tracked separately.  Lets you do all kinds of great things.

Comment: "You should wait a bit." LOL

Comment: In view of _back to the future_ now being in the past, I'm really looking forward to having had waited long enough ;)

Answer (score 50):

You can amend the commit, an example with the year 2037:

```
git commit --amend --date="Wed Feb 16 14:00 2037 +0100"
```

I tried the year 2038 too but then I got a *null* value for the date.

Comment: Anything up to January 19th 3:14:07 2038 UTC should work. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Comment: Amending a commit only changes the committer date. Git tracks 2 dates: commit and author date. Author date will remain as the original via amend or any other git command that edits commits (eg: rebase and cherry-pick).

Comment: @Zombies wrong: `git log` shows `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` by default, not `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE`. You can check with `git log --pretty=fuller` which shows both. Amending the commit with the `--date` option changes the _author date_. Amending it without this option changes only the _commit date_, since it re-creates the commit.

Comment: This only issue of this elegant solution is that it applies only on the last commit. No way to specify a _older_ commit than the tip of the branch.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to retain an actual change-date when adding a project to git, you can do so with

```
env GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="`ls -rt *.cpp|tail -1|xargs date -u -r`" git commit -m "Old sources retaining old change-dates of last changed
 file: `ls -rt *.cpp|tail -1`, actual commit date: `date`"
```

This will commit with the change-date of the last-changed *.cpp-file, and a nice explaining message of the actual commit date.

Answer (score 2):

By combining Hugo's answer ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1474183/1973492)) with information found over here ([2](https://askubuntu.com/a/61182)), and tossing in some `sed`, I got this:

```bsh
alias newest="find . -path ./.git -prune -o -type f -exec stat -c \"%y %n\" '{}' + | sort -r | head -1 | sed s#'.*\./'##"
GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="$(newest | xargs date -u -r)" GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$(newest | xargs date -u -r)" git commit -m "Old sources retaining old change-dates of last changed file: $(newest), actual commit date: $(date)"
```

The main difference is that this version does a recursive search, so you get the latest file anywhere in the tree - though it does skip the .git directory, intentionally.

You may, of course, want to drop one of the date variables here, and I am using a fairly recent version of bash (4.2.37(1)-release), so the $() notation might not work for you (just replace it with backticks (`) instead).

Comment: your `newest | xargs date -u -r` dies on spaces in the filename. sed in the FSF repo supports nul-terminated lines and that'd make the whole pipeline safe but until then I'd say use -d\\n when xarg'ing filenames.  . . . `find . -name .git -prune -o -type d -o -print0 | xargs -0 ls -dt | sed q` is shorter

Answer (score 0):

If you want to amend a commit with a date "from the future" as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5017325/6309):

```
git commit --amend --date="Wed Feb 16 14:00 2037 +0100"
```

- not use a date after 2016 (Git 2.18 or less)
- use Git 2.19 (Q3 2018)

See [commit 1820703](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1820703045f8974bc5320d08a3611f4e29c83bf9) (21 Aug 2018) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1392c5d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1392c5d28935a3aa25367df52adf4ca1e3c5724e), 27 Aug 2018)</sup>

> ### `commit`: use `timestamp_t` for `author_date_slab`
>
> The `author_date_slab` is used to store the author date of a commit when walking with the `--author-date` flag in rev-list or log.
>   This was added as an 'unsigned long' in [81c6b38](https://github.com/git/git/commit/81c6b38b67019eff48e8e5c324bb77f6c796c0b5) ("`log`: `--author-date-order`", June 2013, Git 1.8.4-rc0)
>
> Since '`unsigned long`' is ambiguous in its bit-ness across platforms (64-bit in Linux, 32-bit in Windows, for example), most references to the author dates in `commit.c` were converted to `timestamp_t` in [dddbad7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dddbad728c93280fe54ef86699b6d70e2aab44d1) ("timestamp_t: a new data type for timestamps", April 2017, Git 2.14.0-rc0)
>
> However, the slab definition was missed, leading to a mismatch in the data types in Windows.
>   This would not reveal itself as a bug **unless someone authors a commit after February 2106**, but commits can store anything as their author date.

Answer (score 0):

**Maximum future we can go to**

Also if you want to have some mega-fun and create a commit with the largest date GitHub will accept:

```
d="@$(python -c 'print(2**63 - 1)') +0000"
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$d" git commit -m 'max future' --date "$d"
```

The format `@<number> +0000` create a UNIX timestamp, which is [natively how commit dates are stored in the git commit object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968856/what-is-the-file-format-of-a-git-commit-object-data-structure/37438460#37438460). It is a 64-bit integer, but if we go over `2**63 - 1` GitHub complains about overflow issues:

> remote: error: object a9b376702620cc9a165ba4b5d3599286006b7798: badDateOverflow: invalid author/committer line - date causes integer overflow

[Here's a commit at that date on GitHub](https://github.com/cirosantilli/test-git-web-interface/compare/future-max-2-63-m1):

> Dec 4, 292277026596

The [Futurama time travel song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LE1drY3A418) comes to mind.

Tested on Git 2.40.1, Ubuntu 23.10.

Answer (score -5):

May I ask why you would want to do this?

If you don't want to change your clock, I would suggest creating a script to do the commit and use the Windows Scheduler (or whatever equivalent for your OS) to run the script at the time you want the commit to be.

Comment: Good idea.  In Unix like systems you could use the "at" command (see "man at" for usage).