# git rebase without changing commit timestamps

Tags: git, timestamp, git-rebase

Would it make sense to perform `git rebase` while preserving the commit timestamps?

I believe a consequence would be that the new branch will not necessarily have commit dates chronologically. Is that *theoretically* possible at all? (e.g. using plumbing commands; just curious here)

If it is theoretically possible, then is it possible in practice with rebase, not to change the timestamps?

For example, assume I have the following tree:

```
master <jun 2010>
  |
  :
  :
  :     oldbranch <feb 1984>
  :     /
oldcommit <jan 1984>
```

Now, if I rebase `oldbranch` on `master`, the date of the commit changes from feb 1984 to jun 2010. Is it possible to change that behaviour so that the commit timestamp is not changed? In the end I would thus obtain:

```
      oldbranch <feb 1984>
      /
 master <jun 2010>
    |
    :
```

Would that make sense at all? Is it even allowed in git to have a history where an old commit has a more recent commit as a parent?

Comment: It's funky that the answer to the question is indeed "you don't need to do anything - that's how it works be default". But now suppose you want commit to be sorted in proper date order while doing rebase (which is pretty natural scenario if you think about it). Now, I wasn't able to find how to achieve that, and posted my q as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270357/really-flatten-a-git-merge

Comment: David mentions another option to reset committer date: `git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date SHA`. See [my edited answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2976598/6309)

Comment: I just wrote an [extensive answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30819930/4265352) on a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30790645/4265352) whose author tried the answers explained here and couldn't apply them in a satisfactory manner.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

A crucial question of Von C helped me understand what is going on: when your rebase, the *committer's* timestamp changes, but not the *author's* timestamp, which suddenly all makes sense. So my question was actually not precise enough.

The answer is that rebase actually doesn't change the author's timestamps (you don't need to do anything for that), which suits me perfectly.

Comment: +1 - I have a git alias in place (https://coderwall.com/p/euwpig/a-better-git-log) that apparently uses the committer's timestamp, which was confusing me. Gitk and git log both show the author's timestamp.

Answer (score 250):

Update June 2014: [David Fraser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120398/david-fraser) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973996/git-rebase-without-changing-commit-timestamps/2976598#comment37479014_2976598) a solution also detailed in "[Change timestamps while rebasing git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7352870/6309)", using the option `--committer-date-is-author-date` (introduced initially in Jan. 2009 in [commit 3f01ad6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3f01ad665493e09aa816d84a872d9874f33a8c16)

> Note that the `--committer-date-is-author-date` option seems to leave the author timestamp, and set the committer timestamp to be the same as the original author timestamp, which is what the [OP Olivier Verdier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/262667/olivier-verdier) wanted.
>
> I found the last commit with the correct date and did:
>
> ```
> git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date SHA
> ```

See [`git am`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am):

> ```
> --committer-date-is-author-date
> ```
>
> By default the command records the date from the e-mail message as the commit author date, and uses the time of commit creation as the committer date.
> **This allows the user to lie about the committer date by using the same value as the author date**.

Note: with Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), git rebase `--committer-date-is-author-date` or `--ignore-date` will also work with:

- interactive rebase (`rebase -i`/`rebase --interactive`)
- for the root commit (`git rebase --root`)

See "[Change timestamps while rebasing git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63751470/6309)".

---

(Original answer, June 2012)

You could try, for a <del>*non-interactive*</del> rebase
(see just above: with Git 2.29, Q4 2020, that will work with an interactive rebase as well)

```
git rebase --ignore-date
```

(from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579643/change-timestamp-while-rebasing-git-branch))

This is passed to [`git am`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am), which mentions:

```
 --ignore-date
```

> By default the command records the date from the e-mail message as the commit author date, and uses the time of commit creation as the committer date.
> This allows the user to lie about the author date by using the same value as the committer date.

For [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase), this option is "Incompatible with the --interactive option."

Since [you can change at will the timestamp of old commit date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454734/how-can-one-change-the-timestamp-of-an-old-commit-in-git) (with [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch)), I suppose you can organize your Git history with whatever commit date order you want/need, even [set it to the future!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367262/git-commit-setting-timestamps-into-the-future).

---

As [Olivier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/262667/olivier) mentions in his question, the **author date** is never changed by a rebase;
From the [Pro Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/ch2-3.html):

> - The author is the person who originally wrote the work,
> - whereas the committer is the person who last applied the work.
>
> So, if you send in a patch to a project and one of the core members applies the patch, both of you get credit.

To be extra clear, in this instance, as Olivier comments:

> **the `--ignore-date` does the opposite  of what I was trying to achieve**!
> Namely, it erases the author's timestamp and replace them with the commits timestamps!
> So the right answer to my question is:
> Do not do anything, since `git rebase`  does actually not change authors' timestamps by default.

---

As [DylanYoung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3124256/dylanyoung) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973996/git-rebase-without-changing-commit-timestamps/2976598#comment119740173_2976598), using "[How to identify conflicting commits by hash during git rebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58698138/6309)":

> Using the `SEQUENCE_EDITOR` variable and rebase interactive, you would just loop over the current `todo` list and add a command setting the `GIT_COMMITER_DATE` to the date of the original commit before each commit in the `todo`.
>
> It's a bit less fiddly because you have the list of original commits to start with (you don't have to hack into git internals to find it), but a bit more work because you have to handle the entire list at once. –
>
> Once you're able to identify the original commit you can do something like:
>
> ```
> git rebase -x 'GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="git show -s --format=%ci ``get_current_commit``" git commit --amend --no-edit
> ```

Comment: Interesting about the arbitrary dates to commit. However, `git rebase --ignore-date` does not work. It changes the dates of the rebased commits.

Comment: @Olivier: strange: did you made a *non*-interactive rebase? And between the Author Date and the Committer Date, are we sure to monitor the "right" date?

Comment: Thanks VonC, the difference between author and committer timestamp, that's what makes it all suddenly clear. I wrote the answer to my question in my post, but feel free to adapt your answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Olivier: good point. I have completed my answer to reflect the difference between the two dates.

Comment: to be more precise: the `--ignore-date` does the *opposite* of what I was trying to achieve! Namely, it erases the author's timestamp and replace them with the commits timestamps! So the right answer to my question is: do not do anything, since `git rebase` does actually not change authors' timestamps by default.

Comment: Note that the `--committer-date-is-author-date` option seems to leave the author timestamp, and set the committer timestamp to be the same as the original author timestamp, which is what Olivier wanted...

Comment: @DavidFraser good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Running `git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date SHA_of_root_commit` on all of my branches zipped them all back together again!  Yay!

Comment: Tip: check status with: `git log --pretty=fuller | egrep '^commit|Date'`

Comment: @VonC In short, there is no way to preserve the committer date with `git-rebase` right? The best you can do is to set the committer date equal to the author date.

Comment: @Utku Yes, that is the idea.

Comment: Sure you can.  Use `git rebase -x` or `git rebase -i` with the `SEQUENCE_EDITOR` environment variable set to a little script, but there are lots of edge cases you'll have to handle I suspect.

Comment: @DylanYoung do you have an example of such a script?

Comment: Not off the top or I'd add an answer, but I believe this is the key: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118364/how-to-identify-conflicting-commits-by-hash-during-git-rebase`.  Once you're able to identify the original commit you can do something like: `git rebase -x 'GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="git show -s --format=%ci ``get_current_commit``" git commit --amend --no-edit`'

Comment: Forgive the formatting, not sure how to do nested backticks in SO.

Comment: Using the SEQUENCE_EDITOR variable and rebase interactive, you would just loop over the current `todo` list and add a command setting the `GIT_COMMITER_DATE` to the date of the original commit before each commit in the `todo`.  It's a bit less fiddly because you have the list of original commits to start with (you don't have to hack into git internals to find it), but a bit more work because you have to handle the entire list at once.

Comment: @DylanYoung Interesting. I have tried and included your comment in the answer. Please edit it if I have misconstrued your contribution.

Comment: `--committer-date-is-author-date` will *not* work if the commit and author dates of a commit already differ. There does not seem to be a way to preserve the **commit** date of the commit in the case that the commit and author dates are different.

Comment: @wheeler true, I suspect it did not matter in the context of the OP though.

Comment: `--committer-date-is-author-date` works for me when i wanted to preserve the old dates.

Answer (score 144):

If you've already screwed up the commit dates (perhaps with a rebase) and want to reset them to their corresponding author dates, you can run:

`git filter-branch --env-filter 'GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE; export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE'`

Comment: I just tried this, but no effect. I got the folowing output: `WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged`. I am using git version 1.7.9.5 on Linux (64 bit)

Comment: I'd like to add another approach if you've already screwed up but don't want to iterate through the whole history:
    `git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date <base_branch>`

This way, git will reset the commit date only for the commits applied upon <base_branch> (which is probably the same branch name you used when you screwed up).

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work in 2016, but @speakman's answer did!

Comment: @speakman's answer didn't work in October 2016, but Andy's did!

Comment: This does not work on Windows. I was able to get it to work using Windows Bash.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11179245/539149 worked as of 2017/07/31, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973996/git-rebase-without-changing-commit-timestamps#comment37478036_11179245 did not.  It's too bad that git so often chooses non-human-oriented defaults due to its unix roots, but thankfully is powerful enough to undo them when needed.

Answer (score 22):

By default, git rebase will set the committer's timestamp to the time when the
new commit is created, but keep the author's timestamp intact. Most of time,
this is the desired behavior, but at some scenarios, we dot not wish to change
the commiter's timestamp either. How can we accomplish that? Well, here is the
trick I usually do.

First, make sure each of the commits you are about to rebase has a unique
commit message and author timestamp (This is where is trick needs improvements, currently it suits my needs though).

Before the rebase, record the committer's timestamp, author's timestamp and commit message of all the commits which will be rebased to a file.

```
#NOTE: BASE is the commit where your rebase begins
git log --pretty='%ct %at %s' BASE..HEAD > hashlog
```

Then, let the actual rebase take place.

Finally, we replace the current committer's timestamp with the one recorded in the file if the commit message is the same by using `git filter-branch`.

```
 git filter-branch --env-filter '__date=$(__log=$(git log -1 --pretty="%at %s" $GIT_COMMIT); grep -m 1 "$__log" ../../hashlog | cut -d" " -f1); test -n "$__date" && export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=$__date || cat'
```

If something goes wrong, just checkout `git reflog` or all the `refs/original/` refs.

Furthormore, you can do the similar thing to the author's timestamp.

For example, if the author's timestamp of some commits are out of order, and
without rearrange these commits, we just want the author's timestamp to show in
order, then the following commands will help.

```
git log --pretty='%at %s' COMMIT1..COMMIT2 > hashlog
join -1 1 -2 1 <(cat hashlog | cut -f 1 | sort -nr | awk '{ print NR" "$1 }') <(cat hashlog | awk '{ print NR" "$0 }') | cut -d" " -f2,4- > hashlog_
mv hashlog_ hashlog
git filter-branch --env-filter '__date=$(__log=$(git log -1 --pretty="%s" $GIT_COMMIT); grep -m 1 "$__log" ../../hashlog | cut -d" " -f1); test -n "$__date" && export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=$__date || cat'
```

Comment: This is a great trick! It allowed me to only rewrite 75 commits instead of 1100+ from using the other answers.

Comment: This is fantastic! Is there a way to modify the script to also preserve the original committer as well?

Comment: @DavidDeMar should be, the same, just change the git log --pretty to record the original email, and modify the script accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

The *real* solution seems to be [from Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/git/comments/jp59k5/rebase_without_changing_commit_timestamps/). Augmented slightly, here it is:

```
git -c rebase.instructionFormat='%s%nexec GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="%cD" git commit --amend --no-edit --allow-empty --allow-empty-message' rebase -i
```

Comment: Please go a bit more into detail why this is the considered the "real" solution

Comment: @dfsg76 because it actually does what was asked without its, ands, or buts. The rest of the answers either reset the commit time to the author time (?!), require messing with the repo to add a post-rewrite hook, or fail when there are duplicate dates and commit messages.

Answer (score 3):

**`post-rewrite` hook**

This hook works for all of `git rebase`, `git pull --rebase` and `git commit --amend`.

.git/hooks/post-rewrite

```
set -eu
echo post-rewrite
if [ ! "${CIROSANTILLI_GITHOOKS_DISABLE:-0}" = 1 ]; then
  declare -a olds
  declare -A oldnew
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
    old="$(echo "$line" | cut -d ' ' -f1)"
    new="$(echo "$line" | cut -d ' ' -f2)"
    oldnew[$old]="$new"
    olds+=("$old")
    news+=("$new")
  done
  git reset --hard "${news[0]}~"
  for old in "${olds[@]}"; do
    new="${oldnew[$old]}"
    git cherry-pick "$new" &>/dev/null
    olddate="$(git log --format='%cd' -n 1 "$old")"
    CIROSANTILLI_GITHOOKS_DISABLE=1 \
      GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$olddate" \
      git commit \
      --amend \
      --no-edit \
      --no-verify \
      &>/dev/null \
    ;
  done
  echo
fi
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/dotfiles/blob/a51bcc324f0cff0eddd4c3bb8654ec223a0adb7b/home/.git_hooks/post-rewrite).

Don't forget to:

```
chmod +x .git/hooks/post-rewrite
```

This is a good way to do `--committer-date-is-author-date` by default on chosen repos, before someone finally patches a config to set it by default.

And it also works with `--committer-date-is-author-date` which does not seem to be exposed on `git pull --rebase`.

See also:

- [What git hooks apply to 'git rebase --continue'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22017029/what-git-hooks-apply-to-git-rebase-continue)
- `man githooks`

Tested on git 2.19, Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Very interesting. +1

Comment: "declare -A " is complaining and it says it has below options "declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]"

Comment: @soMuchToLearnAndShare what's your Bash/OS version? Still exists on Ubuntu 22.04 Bash 5.1.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I have created a utility to fix this!

Go to my Bash framework at https://github.com/hopeseekr/BashScripts/

Here is a direct download link to the script itself: [**git-same-sig-time**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hopeseekr/BashScripts/6e9b6db7739683994f839b972f4eb315bc7d6fd9/git-same-sig-time).

```
git-same-sig-time [FIRST COMMIT]
```

Before (after "Rebase and pull" on GitHub):

[image: git log without signatures]

After running `/code/BashScripts/git-same-sig-time 5f5de8b`:

[image: git log with signatures]

Then you'd need to do a force push:

```
git push -f origin trunk
```

Comment: You might also be interested in `git-mtime` (rewrite the local modified times based on git commit timestamp) and `git-commit-at-modded-time` (which uses the file's modified timestamp as the git commit timestamp).

Answer (score 0):

This is the command I used for my case:

```
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=xaionaro@dx.center git rebase --root -x "bash -c 'git commit --amend --reset-author -CHEAD --date=\"\$(git show --format=%ad -s)\"'"
```

Here `git show --format=%ad -s` extracts the current date and `--date` re-enforces it. And `rebase --root -x` executes the command `bash -c 'git commit --amend --reset-author -CHEAD --date="$(git show --format=%ad -s)"'` for each commit.