# How to reword without changing date of commit?

Tags: git, github

I tried to change the message of a commit.

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

I've tagged the commit with reword and edited message in second window

```
git push
git pull
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git push -f
```

The last two steps remove the duplicate of commits.
Now is all fine but the commit is "authored 6 days ago" but listed in todays date.
But I would like to have them on their original date.

See [here](https://github.com/SchadLucas/BranchTest/commits/master). Commits from `Aug 03, 2013` should be in `Jul 28, 2013`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git rebase without changing commit timestamps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973996/git-rebase-without-changing-commit-timestamps)

Answer (score 1):

First off, the date a commit appears on GitHub (in `/commits`) is the date you `git push`.

The original author date is separate, and always preserved when you use `git rebase` to `fixup` or `reword`. So, you'll probably need to do one of two things to have the dates be consistent:

1. Timetravel. Obviously a no-go (for now).
2. Force-delete the commit and re-commit it, then push it the same day.

The GitHub `<user>/<repo>/commits/<branch>` route is an activity log.

In addition, rebasing already-pushed commits is commonly considered a [horrible practice](https://help.github.com/articles/interactive-rebase), as it messes badly with the git repo's history, so keep that in mind.

Comment: Good answer although force pushing to your own feature branch isn't a bad practice and it's commonly used.