# how to rebase when prettier formatting was applied to whole project

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase, prettier

Someone merged in prettier formatting changes across the whole codebase into our `master/main/develop` branch.

I am now trying to rebase against latest `master/main/develop` branch, and resolve merge conflicts.

Since the conflicts are simply caused by running prettier to format code, is there a way to resolve conflicts automatically **while preserving commit history?** (no new merge commits, no extra formatting commits)

Comment: A similar but more complex situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74364616/automatically-rebasing-an-entire-repo-to-restructure-and-apply-prettier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ProTip™️ Ensure all TeamMates have resolved conflicts for all WIP branches *before* the prettier mass formatting changes are merged! ✨
>
> Once everyone resolved conflicts for their WIP branches ✅
>
> Merge the prettier formatting changes on latest master
>
> Come back here to auto-resolve formatting conflicts!

## Preparation:

Ensure you have the NEW version of prettier installed in your `node_modules`:

```bash
git checkout master
git pull
yarn install
git checkout $FEATURE_BRANCH
```

Now, go to your master branch, and find two commit shas, put this in a notepad:

```bash
# 1. Commit where mass formatting was applied:
export MASS_FORMAT=0r93y82q9afuwiehojpei90ur38qy2huia
# 2. Commit just before that one (with updated prettier version + settings, etc):
export BEFORE_MASS_FORMAT=0ury810r8y32hquofawjp08hru3o2wafij
```

##### Now, you must ask yourself: Did your branch have merge conflicts *before* the prettier mass commit?

If you are certain the answer is "no" you can skip step 1. 
To be extra safe, and gain experience with rebasing, just do step 1.

## 1. Resolve conflicts for changes *before* mass formatting commit:

Additionally, look at the history on your `$FEATURE_BRANCH`, and determine the last sha from master that is in your feature branch. This is called the "fork point" or "merge base", I'll refer to this sha as the `$BASE_SHA`. (The first commit of your PR is the branches "`FOOT`", as opposed to your branches `HEAD`. Just before `FOOT` would be your `$BASE_SHA`.)

Rebase one: Ensure no conflicts before mass formatting changes were applied:

```bash
git checkout $FEATURE_BRANCH
git rebase --onto $BEFORE_MASS_FORMAT $BASE_SHA
```

Resolve conflicts throughout the rebase normally.

## 2. Let's auto-resolve those formatting conflicts!

```bash
FEATURE_BRANCH=`git branch --show-current`
git checkout $MASS_FORMAT &&
git pull &&
yarn install && # pickup new prettier version
git checkout $FEATURE_BRANCH &&
git rebase \
  --strategy-option theirs \ # This is flipped, means "keep my feature branch changes"
  --empty=drop \ # Probably related to formatting.
  --exec "$(echo \
      'yarn prettier --write ' \
        'package.json ' \
        '$(git diff HEAD^..HEAD --name-only) ' \
      '|| echo prettier failed its ok; ' \
      'git add . ' \
      ' && git commit --amend --no-verify --no-edit' \
    )" \
  --onto $MASS_FORMAT $BEFORE_MASS_FORMAT;
```

package.json is listed in the --exec call, so that prettier won't decide to just format all files.

## 3. Finally, run a normal rebase against latest master:

```bash
git pull origin master:master --rebase
```

If you are weary about force pushing, inspect diff:

```bash
git diff origin/$FEATURE_BRANCH
```

If the diff is too big and include unrelated changes from master... you can use range-diff:

```bash
git range-diff $BASE_SHA..origin/$FEATURE_BRANCH $BASE_SHA..$FEATURE_BRANCH
```

And lastly, push up cleanly formatted history:

```
git push --force-if-includes --force-with-lease origin master:master
```

Comment: Related: Deeply rename a variable in a large PR stack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73955372/deeply-rename-a-variable-inside-a-large-pr-stack/73955373#73955373