# Deeply rename a variable inside a large PR stack

Tags: git-rebase

I have a PR with 100 commits, which will be submitted as a number of smaller PRs.

At the bottom of the PR stack, I chose a variable name that I now find odd, and would like to change it throughout each commit, but don't want to tediously resolve merge conflicts everywhere.

Is there a way to automate this, using some cli commands to search+replace the variable name?

Comment: Is this not the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/q/73981158/112968?

Comment: There are some similarities indeed. That other question is focused on eliminating a string/variable name, where the programmer needs to manually change code. This q/a is focused on doing a fully automated rename. More detail included on other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one huge, ugly, but magical command:

WARNING: IF YOU HAVE FILE NAMES WITH SPACES IN THEM, THIS WILL ABSOLUTELY WRECK YOUR HISTORY.

`git fetch && git rebase --empty=drop --exec "ag -0 -l 'YourOldUndesirableString' | xargs -0 sed -ri.bak -e 's/YourOldUndesirableString/YourShinyNewString/g'; git clean -f '**/*.bak'; git add .; yarn prettier --write \$(git diff HEAD^..HEAD --name-only) && git add . && git commit --amend --no-verify --no-edit" --strategy recursive --strategy-option theirs origin/master`

- The `ag` command is `the_silver_searcher`, `brew install the_silver_searcher`
- This command is generally suited for osx.
- Replace `YourOldUndesirableString` and `YourShinyNewString` with your actual strings
- Be sure to replace `<your-base-sha>` with something like `1a2s3d4f`
- Note 90% of this command is inside a rebase `--exec "string"`, maybe there's a way to avoid passing a huge string to git rebase `--exec`, allowing for better formatting of this code.

Comment: --diff-filter=d means "exclude deleted files": stackoverflow.com/a/71190099/565877 –

Comment: Related: rebase over mass formatting via prettier without merge conflicts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71812872/how-to-rebase-when-prettier-formatting-was-applied-to-whole-project/73955601#73955601

Comment: curious you must have a reason for it but... why not just add 101st commit that does the renaming? 

Comment: Easier to read through commit log if there's consistent names across everything. Alternatively, could also just not rename stuff.