# git-rebase: Make bad variable name in large PR stack disappear

Tags: git-rebase

I had a JSX component named AccountNode, and accidentally created a TS interface also named AccountNode, but the two are distinct. One is for a row in a table (ui), and the other is for a piece of data in a tree (a node).

How can I make the "AccountNode" name not appear anywhere in history?

<sub>Similarly, as mentioned in the comments, you may have a bad string constant bring passed around, a so-called "magic string". It may be hard to rewrite code to not use this magic string, but this git rebase recipe will help.</sub>

Comment: Is this not the same as https://stackoverflow.com/q/73955372/112968?

Comment: No they are distinct. One is purely focused on doing a completely automated rename, and another helps you manually eliminate a string. Renaming is stylistic, where as eliminating a string could likely break your program.

Comment: In my case I needed to eliminate a "magic string" which was used likely due to not using typescript. (With typescript it's easy to forward a new parameter through any number of function calls, whereas without typescript, magic strings are more prevalent, because it's rather hard to add a new parameter to pass through N function calls)

Comment: I.e. The string "load_more" is not really a valid node id, it's just a hack. I needed the go through and rewrite code to not use this hack.

Answer (score 0):

Example, I don't want to hard-code the string `"load_more"` so am going to redo/tweak those commits:

`git rebase --exec 'git difflastcommitadded | ag load_more && { echo "found load_more"; git redo; } || echo "ok"' --no-reschedule-failed-exec -i 315abbd5b`

## Setup:

1. Install `ag` (`brew install the_silver_searcher`) (grep/ack alternative)
2. Add this git `difflastcommitadded` alias:

```bash
git config --global --edit
brew install the_silver_searcher
```

Paste:

```
[alias]
  # From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73981158/git-rebase-make-bad-name-in-large-pr-stack-disappear/73981159#73981159
  difflastcommitadded = !git diff HEAD^..HEAD --no-ext-diff --unified=0 --exit-code -a --no-prefix | egrep '^\\+'
```

#### Alternatively, if you want to completely abolish a variable name from a folder in your repo, continue reading this less flexible example:

```bash
git rebase --exec 'ag -0 -l AccountNode ui/app && git redo || echo "ok"' -i 315abbd5b
```

This will rebase, but stop whenever there's a commit that introduced `AccountNode` inside the ui/app folder, undo that commit, and pop those changes into your working directory, so you can fix that in your ide.

Once you fix an instance of `AccountNode` you can proceed with nice safety checks using this script:

```bash
ag -0 -l AccountNode ui/app/pages/AccountManagement2 && echo "still contains AccountNode" || {
  yarn --cwd ui run jest -i && git add . && git commit && git rebase --continue
}
```

In my instance, `git commit` runs prettier+eslint, but not tests (those run in ci right now)

This depends on the `git redo` alias mentioned here: [git rebase - pop each commit into working dir to easily edit, re-use commit msg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73968922/git-rebase-pop-each-commit-into-working-dir-to-easily-edit-re-use-commit-msg/73968923#73968923)