# rewrite commits without changing git id & time

Tags: git, timestamp, commit, rebase

## git timestamp resetting created a new no-name-branch

I made a rebase over many commits, because I had to rewrite the message. Then I used [this for reseting time stamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973996/git-rebase-without-changing-commit-timestamps) and now I've a third branch without name.

The merges aren't also correct

turquoise: *master*
purple: *develope*

[image: image of the current log]

another thing: I pushed it already... >.<

any idea to fix it?
- remove the 3rd no-name-branch
- and link it to the actually branch (before)

## UPDATE -- current problem

well, I could restore it

[image: restored with my "problem" I tried to fix]

I want to remove the phrase: "Navigation Drawer with Fragments [commit x]:" at the begin of some commits

I renamed it with rebase and then used the link above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: You can't.

The commit id is a hash, that beside other things consists of the commit date and the message too. This means the moment you change a commit message, it automatically leads to a different hash.

You have to options:

- Force push your branch (`git push --force`), but that's seldom a good idea. If you have other devs, who already fetched the wrong commits, it may mess up their workspace and when they push that again it will mess up the central repository too. If you are alone, it might be OK. Decide yourself.
- Live with it :)