# Changed AuthorDate and CommitDate after git rebase

Tags: git, version-control, git-rebase

As far as i know GIT is tracking two dates for each commit.

- the `AuthorDate` stores the original time of the commit
- the `CommitDate` originally is set to the same date, but gets changed e.g. if a commit from one branch is pulled into another branch when doing a `git rebase`

I am having a branch, in which I invoked a `git rebase master`.
Now the commits that are only in the branch all show the same date for both the `AuthorDate` and the `CommitDate` (there is a difference of a few seconds between the first and last of roughly 30 commits). The dates happen to be the date of the `rebase` (which is correct for the `CommitDate`).
I think that the `AuthorDate` should not be changed under any circumstances, and especially not if doing something as simple as a `rebase`.

I see the wrong dates in my repository when invoking `git log --format=fuller`. Unfortunately I could not reproduce the issue so far...I'll update the question in case I can reproduce it.

My Git version is 1.9.1.

Does anyone have a clue what went wrong with my `git rebase`?

**Update:**

I think the problem is that I use GIT only locally, and I use `git svn dcommit` to push changes into a remote SVN repository.
I just performed a `svn dcommit` with a clean local branch, and was surprised that this caused a `git rebase`. Afterwards I had the issue with changed `AuthorDate` again.

I do not see exactly how the `svn dcommit` is supposed to work and what's going wrong. But I recently started to do the `git svn dcommit` from different local branches (and not only from local master), and I expected that the SVN repository would just be updated to the state of this local branch then. Well, probably I shouldn't use the SVN/GIT combination.

Comment: It is the expected behavior. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973996/git-rebase-without-changing-commit-timestamps

Comment: In this post they are discussing a change of the commit date, which (as I stated above) indeed is supposed to get changed. In the discussion they mention that the commit date can be reset to the `AuthorDate` - which implies that the `AuthorDate` should not get changed.