# Git filter branch from HEAD

Tags: git

I recently forked, committed, and made a pull request to a public repository where I am not a collaborator. My pull request hasn't been merged yet.

Looking through my commits, I realized I committed using the wrong author name and I want to fix it. I tried doing a rebase, which works great:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~7
```

Then I `edited` all the commits in question and, [based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1320317/1944335), successfully changed the author of the commits.

```
git commit --amend --author "James <email@example.com>" --no-edit && \
git rebase --continue
```

Everything is good so far, but I noticed this changes the commit times to the current time. I want to preserve the previous timestamps. [I tried following this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11179245/1944335), but `filter-branch` appears to have changed the hashes for the *entire* repository.

I probably shouldn't force push this. And even if I did, it probably would make it so that my pull request couldn't be merged. So, I tried looking for a way to run `filter-branch` on the last few commits on the branch, but I couldn't find anything. I tried:

```
git filter-branch --env-filter 'GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE; export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE' HEAD~7
```

But that doesn't work. It exits with the error message:

> Which ref do you want to rewrite?

What should I try to do? Is this possible?

Should I look into the `--committer-date-is-author-date` flag for the rebase? What does that do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the range of revisions you want to `git filter-branch`, like this:

```
git filter-branch --env-filter 'GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE; export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE' HEAD~7..HEAD
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about it. Observe that although the commit date changes, the author date is preserved.

If you think about it, this makes sense, given git's semantics: whenever the commit SHA changes, it's a new commit, and the commit-date should change, too.

---

However, the following should work:

```
$ git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date --onto origin/master master my-feature-branch
```

The above command will take all of the commits on `my-feature-branch` which are *not* in `master`, and rebase them atop `origin/master`. Because of the provided `--committer-date-is-author-date`, the author date will be duplicated to the commit date, but *only if you do not use* `-i` *or* `--interactive`.

This should still work even though you've rewritten your local history, although I haven't tried this.

---

#### Concerning the rebase command:

Here is the general form:

```
$ git rebase --onto NEW_BASE OLD_BASE SOME_BRANCH
```

If `SOME_BRANCH` is a branch from `OLD_BASE`, this will take all of the commits between `OLD_BASE` and `SOME_BRANCH`, and apply them to `NEW_BASE` instead of `OLD_BASE`.

Here is a more specific command, based on the few refs you provided:

```
$ git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date --onto origin/master HEAD~7 my-feature-branch
```

Comment: The flag `--committer-date-is-author-date` didn't really work like I thought it would. Do you know if `filter-branch` can be run on the last few commits?

Comment: According to the docs, `--committer-date-is-author-date` does what you want. However, it is incompatible with the `--interactive` option to `git rebase`. Did you try it without specifying `--interactive`?

Comment: No, I haven't. I'll try that now.

Comment: I actually have no idea how to do a non-interactive rebase. Can you please provide more sample code in your answer? I'd really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: If you know how to rebase interactively, then you know how to rebase non-interactively. Just leave off the `-i` switch. If you're worried about munging your branch, you can always use a new branch, or do `git reset my-feature-branch@{1}` to undo the rebase afterward.

Comment: Note: I've updated the code sample, and made another. You rarely have to explicitly specify all three refs for a rebase, but if you do, you can be guaranteed that it will grab only the commits that you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for the extra example! One quick question: what happens once I start the rebase? I want to call `commit --amend` on each of them. Right now I get the message: `First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it` Again, thank you for your help!

Comment: If you really want to preserve commit dates **and** rebase interactively (e.g. to edit each commit), then you'll need to rebase twice. Do it once the usual way (with `-i`), and then again as I showed above.