# git rebase keep date order

Tags: git, git-rebase

I needed to do a very big git rebase to reorganize all the repository. In order to keep my tree, I used `git rebase --preserve-merges --onto master bf40caa develop`

At first everything worked fine, all the merges are preserved and work OK, however, in source tree I'm left with the following tree:

[image: Git graph]

(To be clear, d25b5ad is the initial commit, and there's no more commits before this one)

That's because, although `d12020e` parent is `b0427f6`, as they are created right in the same time we lose the order. I know this can be solved by changing to `ancestor order` instead of `date order`, but I wonder if there's some way to keep these commits ordered... Maybe adding a delay of 1 second between commits when rebasing? How could I do that?

**edit**: @Enrico Campidoglio, no it's not a duplicate of that other question.... Doing in that way it gets even messier... Let's get a bit more into detail:

In this case I had one big repository that had two modules. We started with one module (let's call it `A`) and once it was """finished""" we started with the other right away (let's call it `B`), in the same tree. Then we decided that we should split each one of these modules to their own repository, so what I wanted to do is to push all the tree up to where `A` was finished to the module-A-repository, and to push "only" the module `B` commits the the module-B-repository.

The thing is that we can't do just that, because the first commit of `B` depends on the whole tree left by `A`. So I made an orphan commit containing the project state as it was when `A` was finished (this commit is the "Initial commit" in the screenshot) and did the rebase of the `B` commits onto this commit.

Then note that if I do as that possible duplication it won't solve it, because this `Initial commit` is done "now", that's way after the first commit of `B`.

However, now I see there's another solution: Make this `Initial commit` date one before the first commit of `B`, then run the "possible duplicate"'s solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git rebase without changing commit timestamps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973996/git-rebase-without-changing-commit-timestamps)