# Github contribuition graph incorrect dates

Tags: git, github, graph, config

I did few pushes into master branch on my github project. I've checked it now, it says they were made on 6th of October.

Anyone knows why this is happening?

And second, smaller question: `git config --global user.name` - setting this one, does it have any impact on contribution on github?

Thanks!

Comment: When were the changes made according to your local repo?

Comment: How Can I check it? I don't have access to my PC now unfortunately

Comment: `git log` or whatever else you use to browse your repo.

Comment: `Date:   Wed Oct 19 22:03:49 2016 +0100`. Yesterday's commit.

Comment: I did other one on 18th, and it shows as it was on 6th

Comment: You said you pushed changes to master branch. When were the changes committed in local repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that you did a `git rebase` at some point in time?

[Git commits have two dates attached to them, `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` and `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE`](https://alexpeattie.com/blog/working-with-dates-in-git). They usually have the same value. But some commands like `git rebase` can change the commit date.

To view both dates you can run `git log --pretty=fuller`.

In GitHub's network uses the `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` to display the project's network in a timeline.

If you want to revert the commit dates back to the author dates, you can try using [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11179245/1253041) [approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2976598/1253041) described in another SO answer.

> I'd like to add another approach if you've already screwed up but don't want to iterate through the whole history: `git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date <base_branch>` This way, git will reset the commit date only for the commits applied upon  (which is probably the same branch name you used when you screwed up). - [speakman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/227911/speakman)

Comment: No worries. Were you able to solve the issue with the dates? What does the full git log date show regarding the `commit`and `author` dates?

Reading your question again, it just came to my mind that your issue could be that you pushed the commits recently but they show up as being made on Oct 6th. Regardless of when you push commits to a remote, the dates that shows up is the one when the commit was actually made, and *not* when they were sent to the remote. 

Could this be the source of the confusion? Maybe your machine was set to a different date?

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey man! No, I might have pushed it twice (once on 6th, other one bit later), that's what might have happen.  Thanks again for Answer, all best!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think setting `user.name` has any affect on contribution. Github links your commits to your profile based on your email id. Ref: https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/