# Git interactive rebase (fixup) preserving original date/time stamps on combined commit

Tags: git, rebase

I'd like to clean up a git repo (github hosted) by git rebase and combining like commits into a single one using the 'fixup' option.
My repo goes back 3 years so I figured I could do this step-wise.
For example, my most recent 5 commits are all OK but the 6th-10th needs to be combined into a single one.  So I do this:

```
git rebase -i @~10
```

That lists them in reverse order and the 10th commit is the one I want to pick.
The next 4 commits are all 'fixup'.
And the remaining 5 are set to 'pick'.

When I finish, I run:

```
git push origin +master
```

The problem is that although the commits are combined, the date shown in github's code view is today's.
I want to simply combine them retaining the date/time stamp on the original commit.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

A possible workaround is to use the --committer-date-is-author-date option when using [`git rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)... but it is not compatible with an interactive rebase.

So you can try and:

- do your interactive rebase,
- *then*, once the rebase is done, [make a `git filter-branch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11179245/6309) to restore the commit dates:

  ```
  git filter-branch --env-filter 'GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE; export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE'
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I need to read about filter-branch you suggested.  Perhaps we can take a step backwards: is there an easier way to accomplish my goal of going through my commit history and combining minor ones into a single commit retaining the date/time stamp of the original?

Comment: @RichardDragon not really: you could first do a rebase interactive, then a second rebase for the most recent commits (which were not combined) with the `--committer-date-is-author-date`.

Comment: Great, your suggestion seems to be working for me, thank you!