# Change commit message with original COMMITTER_DATE

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-amend

I have a GIT repository and would like to change message of one commit. I made following command:

```
git rebase -i HEAD ~ 42
git commit --amend -m "new message"
git rebase --continue
```

Unfortunately, then dates of all subsequent commits change. I would like to keep original value **COMMITTER_DATE**.

How to do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git rebase without changing commit timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973996/git-rebase-without-changing-commit-timestamps)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-rebase%5D+preserve+COMMITTER+DATE