# Remove commit from history without changing anything else (dates, committers)

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

I expected this to be as easy as interactive rebase, but I've noticed that rebase changes commit dates and committers.

What would be the easiest way to remove a commit from history while leaving everything else the same?

Comment: Any change to a commit results in a new, different commit. If you're OK with that, look into filter-branch and/or filter-repo, which give you direct control over all the parts of each new commit as you completely rewrite everything from that point onward. You'll have to get everyone who has a clone of the original repository to discard *their* clone too, and switch to the new repository.

Answer (score 1):

`git rebase` has a [`-x`/`--exec` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--xltcmdgt) which can help.

You can add [environment variables](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_committing) which will, for each commit in the rebase `todo` list, help to keep date/author unchanged:

I mention that in "[git rebase without changing commit timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2976598/6309)"

```
git rebase -i --committer-date-is-author-date \
 -x 'git config user.name "$(git show -s --format=%an $(git rev-parse HEAD))"' \
 -x 'git config user.email "$(git show -s --format=%ae $(git rev-parse HEAD))"' \
 @~x
```

(replace `x` in `@~x` by the number of commits you want your interactive rebase to start)

The problem is: you will need to manually copy those generated lines *before* the first `pick` todo item, in order for the first commit to use those settings.

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately, it does not seem to work for me even in expanded form (where I'm setting all 6 variables). As soon as the rebases reaches the skipped commit, I get `Committer identity unknown *** Please tell me who you are.`. The exec syntax looks strange to be. Are you sure that the quotes are correct? Shouldn't it be `-x 'export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=$(git show -s --format=%an $(git rev-parse HEAD))'` ?

Comment: I suspect that even with export, the environment variables are not getting to GIT.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried multiple approaches using `git rebase` and `git filter-branch`, but neither worked. `git filter-branch` likely cannot work, since it operates on snapshots, while removing commits require operating on change-sets/patches.

The only solution that worked was to create my own rebase based on `git cherry-pick`:

```sh
# !!! Only do this when the working copy is clean !!!
git checkout --orphan new_branch
# Now clean up all the files
# !!! Careful !!!
# git reset --keep

git log --reverse --format=%H source_branch |
  grep -v -E "sha1|sha2|sha3" |
  while read sha; do
   (
    echo "Cherry-picking $(git show --no-patch --format=oneline "$sha")"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=$(git show -s --format=%cn "$sha")
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=$(git show -s --format=%ce "$sha")
    export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=$(git show -s --format=%cd "$sha")
    git cherry-pick "$sha" -Xtheirs
   )
  done
```