# set commit message for future git commit

Tags: git

Is there a way to set a comment for the next future commit using git? Imagine something like this:

```
git next-commit "Implement client-side validation"

# implement the feature ...

# commit changes
# equivalent to git commit -m "Implement client-side validation"
git commit -m from-next-commit
```

The motivation behind this is that I often have a particular feature in mind when I'm programming, but along the way I end up developing some other features or fixing related things and I lose track of the main task I was working on.

At that point I have modified the source code with useful changes, but I don't even remember what the main feature I added is, since it's all just a bunch of changes and the only commit message I can think of is `git commit -m "Update stuff"`. Setting the message for the next commit could also help me keep working on what I was supposed to do. At any point if I feel like I've forgotten the main task and have derailed to other feature, I would ideally ask git with something like `git next-commit`, which could print `Implement client-side validation`.

Does a feature like this exist?

EDIT: after seeing some answers, I think I should clarify another thing. Ideally, this command would also help you keep track of when the future commit has already been used. For example, if you use `git commit -m from next-commit` twice without setting a new future commit message before, it should fail.

```
$ git next-commit "Implement client-side validation"
ok
$ git commit -m from-next-commit
ok
# git commit -m from-next-commit
error : already used
$ git next-commit "Optimize get_request"
ok
$ git commit -m from-next-commit
ok
```

Comment: have you seen this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29927453/use-future-date-while-making-git-commits

Comment: I don't think that thread is related, it's focused on setting dates rather than commit messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would do what [Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54741453/179715) suggested, but it wouldn't be terribly hard to do what you want if you're willing to use a custom command instead of `git commit`.

That is, you could make a custom `git-next-commit` script, put it in `PATH`, and have it write your desired commit message to some file in the root of your git repo (or maybe in `.git/`).

Then make another custom script (e.g. `git-commit-from-next`, or just reuse `git-next-commit`, possibly with a command-line option) that invokes `git commit` with the previously stored message and deletes the file.  If the file doesn't exist, then print an appropriate error message.

You also might be able to get the [git prepare-commit-msg hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_prepare_commit_msg) to do what you want if it sees a special "from-next-commit" message.

Comment: James, it should be possible to setup a pre-commit hook which reads a commit message from a file somewhere.  Then, you'd only need some command line program which writes a message to that file.  Downside: then you might loose the ability to easily choose a message when you actually commit.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen My thinking was to use the prepare-commit-msg hook (not the pre-commit hook) to check for some special "from-next-commit" message, replace the contents of the commit message if found, and otherwise leave everything alone.  Looking at the prepare-commit-msg hook some more, I think it should be possible (but I haven't spent the time to actually implement it).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps use `git commit -F <file>` to read the comment from a file?

Comment: I do this occasionally. It's useful when working on a long feature. I put the message in a .commit file, and edit the message during the work. In between, I make small commit with message starting with "... ". In the end, make the final commit with the .commit file.

Comment: maybe -e flag. `git commit -eF <file>` lets you edit the message in the final commit

Answer (score 2):

Honestly if you are having so much trouble remembering what you did in the current commit, I might question whether you would even be in a good state the review all the code before making that commit.  Maybe you should invest in an issue tracker like Jira.

That being said, one trick you might find useful here would be to start off by making a dummy commit, where you just make a small change somewhere.  Add the "future" commit message you have in mind via:

```
git commit -m 'Implement client-side validation'
```

Then, do your work and finish the commit.  When it comes time to commit this work, you may *amend* the previous commit:

```
git commit --amend
```

This should by default bring up an editor window, in which you should see your future commit message already there.

Comment: True enough, if having trouble remembering things, would be better to add a note somewhere to keep track of things you're doing and have done.

Comment: I think that was the point of the answer, to use git as a quick way to add that note.

Comment: The problem with `git commit --amend` is that it's always possible to run it. Ideally, once you commit with the future comment you set before, the comment would be deleted, and you would have to set a new future comment to do it again.

Comment: @MeiZhang When I gave this answer, I was assuming that the commit message would change with each commit, which in 10+ years of using Git has been my general experience.

Comment: Of course I want to change the message with every commit, maybe I didn't explain myself well. What I'm saying is that an ideal solution would also keep track of when the future commit has already been used.
For example, the second time you try to use it, it should fail:

`$ git next-commit "Implement client-side validation"
ok
$ git commit -m from-next-commit
ok
# git commit -m from-next-commit
error : already used, set a new next-commit first`. The probem with `git commit --amend`, it's something that can be done at any time without any checks.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to cut a branch with the "description" you have in mind (e.g. `git checkout -b "mz-client-side-validation"`. Remember the commit at which you started this branch (use a tag, say `mz-csv` if you need to) and then begin your work. It doesn't matter at first if you're not focused with the nature of your work. What you should get into the habit of is making small commits (even with bad messages). So while the commits are not always related to client-side-validation, they are small enough to be useful in the history.

Once you're done implementing your actual feature (perhaps via. multiple commits), do a `git rebase -i mz-csv`. Now you can clean up the history of work on `mz-client-side-validation`. Cut up commits, merge them, drop them etc. and when you're ready, merge `mz-client-side-validation` back into the main branch.